# CSRF tips and solution

Tags: php, security, projects-and-solutions

So, I have made a class that inserts automatically in all forms an: `<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="csrf_value_uniq_id" />`

Now my problems is that, I set the key to expire after 5 minutes, but if you stay on the page or you go to eat when you come back and you submit the form the csrf keys won't match.

Now, I could set this to expire in 24hours but then I don't know if this will be as safe as is meant to do.I'm using it on post forms.

So what's the best solution how should I do this?

Comment: Take another look at your question -- looks like you left the code fragment out?

Comment: The key should expire when client makes a new request. The key belongs to the current client and should not be available to others.

Comment: @Repox Expiring the key upon a new request can be annoying, since this makes HTTP requests depend on server state and not idempotent. It prevents users from opening several tabs at once, for instance.

Comment: It's a good idea to expire the token on a session principal change (eg: Login), as a defence against session fixation attacks. But indeed expiring on *every* request makes your app painful to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

A solution which does not require a server-side state and thereby a timeout is a *signed token*. You create a random value which you include into the form, then you *sign* that token with a secret only you know:

```
$secret    = 'weufiwu93tu2b248hg24';
$token     = uniqid('', true);
$signature = sha1($secret . ':' . $token);
```

You then embed the token and the signature into the form. Upon receiving the form again, you repeat the `SHA1(secret:token)` operation with the token from the form and compare the result to the signature from the form. If you have a well chosen, random secret and a robust hash, nobody will be able to sign the token but the one who knows the secret, hence you have proven that the token came from you.

In addition, you can include a timestamp in the form/signature to limit the validity of the token (make it longer than 5 minutes, but not long enough for the token to be usable forever), the user id to tie a token to a specific user, the expected form fields to protect against form field injection and whatever else you may want to check against. E.g.:

```
signature = SHA1(secret:token:timestamp:userid:[form_field_name[:...]])
```

For the above signature, you embed the signature, token, timestamp and obviously the form fields in the form; upon submission you check that the submitted timestamp is within a certain window, take the secret and userid from the server, recreate the signature with all those pieces and check it against the submitted signature.

Note that the above *code* is just an example, your token should use a better source of randomness and be longer and your hashing function should be something more robust like HMAC or bcrypt. This here is to convey the *idea*, not the implementation details.

---

An actual implementation can be found here: [Kunststube\CSRFP](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP). I put this together in response to this question, since I needed something like it anyway.

Comment: To make this work you need to bind the secret to the user. Otherwise an attacker can simply use his tokens for the forged requests.

Comment: @Gumbo Yup, was still adding details. Hope I have included everything now.

Comment: Consider also HMAC. Although in practical terms a straight SHA1 is probably good enough, what this is doing is really message authentication so it's a good idea to use the best-practice standard form.

Comment: @bobince ...as mentioned in the last paragraph... :)

Comment: @bobince Waddaya know, just implemented such a signature CSRF for the fun of it here: https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP. I'd be glad if you could have a look for any obvious faux-pas.

Comment: @deceze: looks good from first impressions! Might be worth mentioning that this is also good for forgotten-password reset links. Although SHA-512 might be a bit overlong for that purpose. Also I wonder if it might be possible to support in-band values (ie included in the signature rather than known in advance or passed in a separate parameter).

Comment: @bobince Thanks. Good points. I'll think about those. Password reset links would be a use case for in-band values, I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways an attacker can get a valid token:

1. he is able to guess/predict the token, or
2. he is able to obtain it from a client.

The former can be mitigated by using a proper random source with enough entropy. The latter can be established by securing the transmission (i.e. HTTPS) and by protecting against attacks like Cross-Site Scripting which can be used to obtain a user’s token.

If you do both, you can even make it never expire (or at the end of the user’s session).

Comment: Had nothing better to do, so I put together an implementation of what I'm talking about in my answer here: https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP. This being security related and all, I'd be happy about some peer criticism... :)